# Limit resizing of images with explicitly set width and height attributes

Tags: html, css, image

I have a set of images for which I am specifying explicit width and height attributes in the HTML, so that space is reserved for them while the page is loaded (this avoids page "jumps" when images take longer to load).

On the other hand I don't ever want the images to take more space than the available width of the viewport. So if the viewport is too narrow the images should resize. For this I added the following CSS styles:

```
img.resizable {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

The problem: As soon as I set `height:auto` in the CSS, space for the image is not reserved anymore during page loads and I get the page "jumps" effect. If I remove `height:auto`, then if the image resizes the aspect ratio will not be preserved. Any suggestions on how to approach this?

A non-Javascript solution would be preferred if possible.

Comment: Since the height would depend both on the width of available space and on the intrinsic dimensions of the image, I cannot imagine how you could do this without using JavaScript to load the images, inspect them, determine the available widths, and insert specific width and height properties (in pixels), in code that is executed before any rendering takes place. This sounds far too complicated and ineffective; the cure would be worse than the disease, I’m afraid.

Comment: Yet it is possible to do it in a relatively easy way and without any Javascript. I just found a working solution, see my answer.

Comment: If those are the only CSS rules that you apply to your img that regard height and width, it would keep it's aspect ratio. So i think your problem first off is that some other CSS is interfering with your images.

Comment: @ThanGhil Please read the question again. I am explicitly saying that with these CSS properties, the aspect ratio is kept, but the page jumps are back. If I remove height:auto, **then** page jumps are gone but aspect ratio is not preserved.

Comment: Ok, since you know the height of all images then add them together and you set your container/body height accordingly. The "page jumps" will be invisible since you reserve the height with your static body.

Comment: @ThanGhil: You are missing the point. The question was related to how explicit height interact with the resizing behaviour. Please re-read the question where I explain what is the problem exactly. I also posted an answer explaining how I solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with hints from [this blog post](http://ansciath.tumblr.com/post/7347495869/css-aspect-ratio) that explains how to use CSS to set the aspect ratio of a fluid element.

Basically the solution looks as follows:

```
<div style="width: [width]px; max-width:100%; position:relative">
    <div style="padding-top: [aspect]%"></div>
    <img style="position:absolute; top:0" src="...">
</div>
```

where: `[width]` = image width, `[aspect]` = 100 * image width / image height

Basically with this the browser has the following information:

- The initial width of the image (set in the outer div via `width`)
- The aspect ratio (set in the inner div via `padding-top`)
- The resizing behaviour (set in the outer div via `max-width`)

With this I achieve the desired behaviour: No page jumps upon initial load, and automatic resizing (keeping the aspect ratio) for narrow viewports.

Comment: This answer only works if you know your image's width and height beforehand.

Comment: Of course. That is obvious from the question: "I have a set of images for which I am specifying explicit width and height attributes in the HTML"